# Code snippet to be executed before every page on server

Tags: apache2

I have an apache2 server, it has quite a vast and growing folder structure.

There is a set of instruction I would like to be executed at the beginning of every single page in that website.

How do I implement that without just pasting those very lines at the beginning of every single file in the website?

I have apache server, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script with the instructions and execute it with php shell exec function at the top of all your pages so when they load it executes the shell script. Or any other functions you need to for that matter in any language.

Comment: That's what I used to do but I would like to just 'write once'.

Comment: If all the pages are static html you may want to do a find and replace and add the php function to all of them or think about switching to a CMS. I don't think there's another way to execute a script each time a page loads any other way. Or use server side includes and have one header file included in all your HTML files which has the php function

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the 'auto_prepend_file' and 'auto_append_file' directives in php.ini.

Comment: I changed that line to auto_prepend_file =~/website_preview/say_hello.php then i restarted the server but nothing changes.